# Improve MySQL Query with IN Subquery

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, explain

I hava a table `items` and a table `item_attributes`.

For simplicity let's say my table item has a column `id` and a column `name`.
Of cource there is a index on the `id` column.

the `item_attributes` table has the columns `id`, `item_id`, `attribute_name` and `attribute_value` and an index ON `attrubute_name`

Now I want to query all items with a specific attribut without using a join.

I do this with the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM items i
WHERE i.id IN (
    SELECT item_id
    FROM item_attributes a
    WHERE a.attribute_name = 'SomeAttribute'
      AND a.attribute_value = 'SomeValue'
)
```

the SubQuery itself runs fast.

If I execute the query itself first and use the result for an IN query

```
SELECT *
FROM items i
WHERE i.id IN (1,3,5,7,10,...)
```

it is fast, too.

However, combined the query is very, very slow (>2 secs.)
If I investigate the query plan I see why: MySQL does a full table scan on the items table instead of executing the subquery first and using the result for an index query.

```
1, 'PRIMARY', 'items', 'ALL', '', '', '', '', 149726, 'Using where'
2, 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'item_attributes', 'index_subquery', 'IDX_ATTRIBUTE_NAME', 'IDX_ATTRIBUTE_NAME', '4', 'func', 1, 'Using where'
```

Is there a way to optimize this query? I know that the subquery will always return only a small resultset (<100 rows).

Comment: What prompts you to want to do this without the use of a `JOIN`?

Comment: I can't use join because this is only a small piece of the full picture. I use C# with an ORM and I just add the `WHERE master.primarykey IN (dynamic subquery)` piece to an existing in memory query object that is later converted to plain SQL. I can't use a JOIN because I would need to add a group by clause but that would restrict the calling function.

Comment: @Schla: in your model, can you have two records with the same `attribute_name` for an item?

Comment: @Quassino: Sure, ever item can have an attribute with the name `InStock` for example.

Comment: that's not what I asked. Can an item (one item) have two attributes called `InStock`?

Comment: Yes, attributes don't have to be unique. My SubQuery sometimes returns an id multiple times which will result in a `SELECT * FROM item WHERE id IN (3,5,3)` query. But that's ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MySQL` cannot switch the leading and the driven table in the `IN` clause. This is going to be [corrected in `6.0`](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/6.0_Subquery_Optimization_Cheatsheet).

For now, you can rewrite it like this (requires a `JOIN`):

```
SELECT  i.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT item_id
        FROM    item_attributes a
        WHERE   a.attribute_name = 'SomeAttribute'
                AND a.attribute_value = 'SomeValue'
        ) ai
JOIN    items i
ON      i.id = ai.item_id
```

Since you are using the `EAV` model you may want to make a unique index on `(attribute_name, item_id)` in which case you can use a plain join:

```
SELECT  i.*
FROM    item_attributes ai
JOIN    items i
ON      i.id = ai.item_id
WHERE   a.attribute_value = 'SomeValue'
        AND a.attribute_name = 'SomeAttribute'
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know that the mysql team is working on this. For the moment I rewrote my code to perform two queries. One to get the id's and another `SELECT ... FROM item WHERE id IN (1,3,5,7,10)`. I wanted to avoid this to reduce the size of the query string but for now this is better than a poor query execution performance.

Answer (score 1):

inner join does better and more efficient

```
select i.* 
from items i
inner join item_attributes ia on i.id=ia.item_id
where ia.attribute_name='SomeAttribute' AND ia.attribute_value='SomeValue';
```

if the primary key for item_attributes is for item_id+attribute_name,
then no GROUP BY is required

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `exists`

```
SELECT *
FROM items i
WHERE Exists
(
    SELECT item_id
    FROM item_attributes a
    WHERE 1=1
      AND i.id = a.ItemId
      AND a.attribute_name = 'SomeAttribute'
      AND a.attribute_value = 'SomeValue'
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.*
FROM items i, item_attributes ai
WHERE i.id = ai.item_id AND a.attribute_name = 'SomeAttribute' AND a.attribute_value = 'SomeValue'
```